# How to get spline-object intersection in maxscript?

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I have faced a problem in maxscript.

I want to find the intersection points between spline(circle) and object in maxscript.

[image]

I tried to use `intersects` between surface and each circle.
Like this:

```
intersects o_surface s_circle
```

But it returns only **true**.

How can I find the intersection points like above image in maxscript?

Comment: It is not possible to find it directly with maxscript, if I had this task, I would approach it with custom maxscript plugin implemented in C++, that would find spline-mesh intersections and return it to maxscript as array of Point3. You can contact me for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much.
I tried to solve myself, and found the way.
I will share my solution through answer